# How to get value of non-selected text from Select DropDown by jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Suppose I have a DropDown --

```
    <select  id="myId">
     <option value="0">-- Select Option -- </option>
     <option value="1">Red</option>
     <option value="2">Green</option>
     <option value="3">White</option> </select>
```

How can I get the value 3 for white like

```
var value1=$("#myId option[name='White']").val();
```

This doesn't work.

Comment: `option[name='White']`  is wishful thinking

Comment: `var text = "White";
console.log(
  $("select option:contains("+text+")").attr("value")
) `